# invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x7acd0bd0 passed to dlfree

Tags: android, s5

Device : Glaxy S5
Model:SM-G900H
Android Version:4.4.2

Application force when I open/close activity several times.Or I launch and close my app several times.
Same occures when I resume ( by pressing power button to pause it) my Activity multiple time.

### Following is the trace which is generated when app force closes.

```
07-02 16:40:12.446: A/libc(28655): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x7acd0bd0 passed to dlfree
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] DalvikVM version 2014.2.24_1
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         jitOpt ON
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         ldrHoist ON
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         strSink ON
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         licm ON
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         loopInverse ON
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         traceStrSink OFF
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         patternMatching ON
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [0] CodeCache(0x7982d59c ~ 0x7982d664; 200 bytes), Info(String;,hashCode,0x16)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         STR_SINKING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [1] CodeCache(0x7982d75c ~ 0x7982d838; 220 bytes), Info(String;,regionMatches,0x3b)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [2] CodeCache(0x7982da78 ~ 0x7982db58; 224 bytes), Info(Hashtable$HashI,nextEntry,0x2b)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [3] CodeCache(0x7982ddc0 ~ 0x7982de68; 168 bytes), Info(String;,lastIndexOf,0x20)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [4] CodeCache(0x7982dfa8 ~ 0x7982e0b8; 272 bytes), Info(String;,<init>,0x51)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [5] CodeCache(0x7982e9d4 ~ 0x7982ea6c; 152 bytes), Info(HashMap;,put,0x2a)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [6] CodeCache(0x798303d4 ~ 0x79830478; 164 bytes), Info(HashMap;,doubleCapacity,0x1a)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [7] CodeCache(0x79830760 ~ 0x79830804; 164 bytes), Info(HashMap;,doubleCapacity,0x14)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [8] CodeCache(0x798337a0 ~ 0x79833860; 192 bytes), Info(ObjectIdentifie,toIntArray,0x84)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [9] CodeCache(0x798339a0 ~ 0x79833aa0; 256 bytes), Info(ObjectIdentifie,toIntArray,0x87)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [10] CodeCache(0x79834dac ~ 0x79834e70; 196 bytes), Info(HashMap;,containsKey,0x33)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [11] CodeCache(0x79834ff0 ~ 0x798350a8; 184 bytes), Info(BigInteger;,twosComplement,0x89)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         STR_SINKING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [12] CodeCache(0x798350a8 ~ 0x7983514c; 164 bytes), Info(BigInteger;,twosComplement,0x87)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [13] CodeCache(0x79836630 ~ 0x79836710; 224 bytes), Info(HashMap$HashIte,nextEntry,0x27)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [14] CodeCache(0x798374b0 ~ 0x7983758c; 220 bytes), Info(Arrays;,equals,0x1b)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [15] CodeCache(0x79837ec8 ~ 0x79837fd4; 268 bytes), Info(ByteArrayBuffer,append,0x2b)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         STR_SINKING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [16] CodeCache(0x798383dc ~ 0x798384cc; 240 bytes), Info(File;,fixSlashes,0x1e)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [17] CodeCache(0x7983924c ~ 0x79839330; 228 bytes), Info(BerInputStream;,readOID,0x7b)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [18] CodeCache(0x79839330 ~ 0x7983940c; 220 bytes), Info(AttributeTypeAn,hashIntArray,0x8)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [19] CodeCache(0x798394fc ~ 0x798395cc; 208 bytes), Info(Strings;,asCharArray,0x7)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [20] CodeCache(0x798396f8 ~ 0x798397e8; 240 bytes), Info(CharArrayBuffer,append,0x31)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [21] CodeCache(0x79839854 ~ 0x79839920; 204 bytes), Info(AbstractSession,locateLF,0xf)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [22] CodeCache(0x7983a434 ~ 0x7983a4e8; 180 bytes), Info(FastXmlSerializ,escapeAndAppend,0x14)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [23] CodeCache(0x7983be48 ~ 0x7983bf08; 192 bytes), Info(ViewGroup;,findViewTravers,0x1c)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [24] CodeCache(0x7983d23c ~ 0x7983d2e0; 164 bytes), Info(SpannableString,getSpanFlags,0x11)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [25] CodeCache(0x7983df00 ~ 0x7983dfa4; 164 bytes), Info(SpannableString,getSpanStart,0x18)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [26] CodeCache(0x7983e0e0 ~ 0x7983e188; 168 bytes), Info(Parcel;,recycle,0x1c)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [27] CodeCache(0x7983e274 ~ 0x7983e32c; 184 bytes), Info(ReplacementTran,getChars,0x20)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [28] CodeCache(0x7983eb5c ~ 0x7983ec00; 164 bytes), Info(SpannableString,getSpanEnd,0x18)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [29] CodeCache(0x79841cc4 ~ 0x79841d8c; 200 bytes), Info(Arrays;,hashCode,0xa)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         STR_SINKING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [30] CodeCache(0x79842824 ~ 0x798428f8; 212 bytes), Info(BufferedReader;,readLine,0x96)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [31] CodeCache(0x79843c50 ~ 0x79843d18; 200 bytes), Info(UriCodec;,validate,0x26)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [32] CodeCache(0x79844c08 ~ 0x79844cf4; 236 bytes), Info(String;,equalsIgnoreCas,0x37)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [33] CodeCache(0x79846adc ~ 0x79846ba0; 196 bytes), Info(HashMap;,get,0x36)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [34] CodeCache(0x79847b38 ~ 0x79847bec; 180 bytes), Info(CharArrayBuffer,indexOf,0x11)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [35] CodeCache(0x79848360 ~ 0x79848434; 212 bytes), Info(UriCodec;,validateSimple,0x32)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [36] CodeCache(0x7984ad50 ~ 0x7984ae0c; 188 bytes), Info(Arrays;,fill,0x4)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [37] CodeCache(0x7984d0c4 ~ 0x7984d1b8; 244 bytes), Info(IntegralToStrin,convertInt,0xb5)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         STR_SINKING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [38] CodeCache(0x79850a04 ~ 0x79850ad4; 208 bytes), Info(SimpleDateForma,parseText,0x10)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [39] CodeCache(0x79852634 ~ 0x79852700; 204 bytes), Info(RelativeLayout$,findRoots,0x47)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [40] CodeCache(0x79852978 ~ 0x79852a48; 208 bytes), Info(BoringLayout;,isBoring,0x93)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [41] CodeCache(0x7985659c ~ 0x79856690; 244 bytes), Info(IntegralToStrin,intIntoCharArra,0x28)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         STR_SINKING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [42] CodeCache(0x79858410 ~ 0x798584e4; 212 bytes), Info(Arrays;,fill,0x7)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [43] CodeCache(0x7985a2f8 ~ 0x7985a3b4; 188 bytes), Info(Arrays;,binarySearch,0x11)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [44] CodeCache(0x7985a3b4 ~ 0x7985a46c; 184 bytes), Info(GregorianCalend,computeFields,0x2f)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         STR_SINKING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [45] CodeCache(0x7985a4bc ~ 0x7985a598; 220 bytes), Info(Calendar;,clear,0x6)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [46] CodeCache(0x7985f348 ~ 0x7985f3e4; 156 bytes), Info(LinkedList$Link,<init>,0x41)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [47] CodeCache(0x7985f5fc ~ 0x7985f6a4; 168 bytes), Info(Parcel;,obtain,0x13)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [48] CodeCache(0x7985f890 ~ 0x7985f934; 164 bytes), Info(ViewGroup;,dispatchCancelP,0x13)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [49] CodeCache(0x7986b798 ~ 0x7986b840; 168 bytes), Info(HashMap;,doubleCapacity,0x38)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [50] CodeCache(0x7986cdc4 ~ 0x7986ce80; 188 bytes), Info(ContainerHelper,binarySearch,0xd)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [51] CodeCache(0x7986d1ac ~ 0x7986d320; 372 bytes), Info(IntegralToStrin,convertInt,0x91)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [52] CodeCache(0x79870638 ~ 0x798706f0; 184 bytes), Info(CharArrayBuffer,indexOf,0x17)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [53] CodeCache(0x79870e04 ~ 0x79870f10; 268 bytes), Info(ASN1Oid;,getDecodedObjec,0x28)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [54] CodeCache(0x79880d20 ~ 0x79880e00; 224 bytes), Info(HashMap$HashIte,<init>,0x1f)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [55] CodeCache(0x7988ac28 ~ 0x7988ad40; 280 bytes), Info(ZoneInfo;,<init>,0xa1)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         STR_SINKING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [56] CodeCache(0x7989a50c ~ 0x7989a5b0; 164 bytes), Info(GregorianCalend,fullFieldsCalc,0x29)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         STR_SINKING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [57] CodeCache(0x7989b1f0 ~ 0x7989b2cc; 220 bytes), Info(Arrays;,equals,0x1b)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [58] CodeCache(0x7989e348 ~ 0x7989e3fc; 180 bytes), Info(NetworkInterfac,getNetworkInter,0x3e)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [59] CodeCache(0x798a5ff4 ~ 0x798a60b8; 196 bytes), Info(LinkedHashMap;,get,0x3e)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [60] CodeCache(0x798ae280 ~ 0x798ae374; 244 bytes), Info(ContainerHelper,binarySearch,0xf)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [61] CodeCache(0x798af840 ~ 0x798af8ec; 172 bytes), Info(String;,trim,0x14)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LOOP_INVERSION
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [62] CodeCache(0x798b0f58 ~ 0x798b1034; 220 bytes), Info(Arrays;,areEqual,0x1d)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE] [63] CodeCache(0x798baf60 ~ 0x798bb028; 200 bytes), Info(IntegralToStrin,intToHexString,0x9)
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LDR_HOISTING
07-02 16:40:12.446: D/dalvikvm(28655): [SWE]         LICM
07-02 16:40:12.446: A/libc(28655): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 28899 (AsyncTask #7)
```

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196013/why-application-is-dying-randomly)