# Invalid address passed to dlfree

Tags: android

My app seems to be crashing "randomly" and I can't figure out why.

The logcat shows the following error:

```
A/libc(24298): invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x78366c48 passed to dlfree
A/libc(24298): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 24322 (AsyncTask #5)
```

Could this be something I am doing?  Is it something wrong with Android?

I'm not really sure where to start looking for this at.

The person who is seeing this crash did tell me they have "a bad SD card and Verizon is telling me I need to put a new one in."  That may or may not be relevant.

Comment: It's your application if you have some native (ndk) code in it or it is from a library you are using. It is very unlikely that you have found a strange bug in Android framework. You need to provide more information.

Comment: gonna need more information.

Comment: try debugging native allocations https://source.android.com/devices/native-memory.html

Comment: Hi Andrew did u find a solution.

Comment: Hi @andrew, did you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 25):

It's hard to solve this issue with no code to look at or any clue what the app is about, but I'll give you my guess what can cause the problem, and hopefully this will lead you in the right direction to solve this issue.

First of `SIGSEGV`, is a segmentation fault. Which in other words means that a memory access violation, trying to access memory which you are not allowed to. A likely cause of this is that you have ran out of memory, maybe because a memory leak or simply used up all memory. This can be caused by a bug you are using in a plugin that uses native C/C++ code through NDK.

The error code 0xDEADBAAD ("dead bad") is used by the Android libc abort() function when native heap corruption is detected.

In my opinion your best shot is to try and recreate the problem in the emulator or get hold of a device which can cause the problem and start [`debugging memory`](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html) to get a hunch of the cause of this.

I would also recommend you to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196013/why-application-is-dying-randomly) SO question which has similar problems.

Good luck, solving the issue!

Best regards,
Rawa

Comment: I had a similar problem with my android settings and some other apps. In the log file `/data/tombstones/tombstone_01` in the `stack:` section I found that an app (in my case 'macchanger') was causing the issue. I don't know, maybe that app is malicious but I was not expecting an app to reproducible crash other apps (kinda scary).

Comment: @JepZ that was a life saver! My device crashed in the middle of updating an app, and was in a boot-loop since. Thanks to your comment I was able to figure what directory to remove (that app now existed twice, and the second instance was mentioned in every tombstone), and my device booted up fine again.

Comment: @Rawa I have a similar crash happening, Please help me if you can I was able to get tombstone file as I can recreate it in Emulator too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836896/signal-11-sigsegv-code-1-segv-maperr-fault-addr-0x7f4485ff1820