# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7f4485ff1820

Tags: android, segmentation-fault

My app has been crashing randomly with signal 11. I was able to get my hands on tombstone file from emulator but I am not able to understand what is wrong with my app. I have gone through many posts here with the same error but haven't found a working solution yet. I am attaching my stack-trace file here please help me understand the problem and how can I fix it.

Here is logcat from the crash

```
                --------- beginning of crash
12-15 21:09:25.003 2865-2875/in.myapp.dev A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7f4485ff1820 in tid 2875 (FinalizerDaemon)
12-15 21:09:25.006 2865-2878/in.myapp.dev I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 35304(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 13(531KB) LOS objects, 22% free, 13MB/17MB, paused 355us total 119.765ms
12-15 21:09:25.180 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-15 21:09:25.180 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:5.1.1/LMY48X/3287191:userdebug/test-keys'
12-15 21:09:25.180 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
12-15 21:09:25.180 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86_64'
12-15 21:09:25.180 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG: pid: 2865, tid: 2875, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> in.myapp.dev <<<
12-15 21:09:25.180 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x7f4485ff1820
12-15 21:09:25.392 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     rax 00007f249892b630  rbx 0000000400000004  rcx 0000000000000000  rdx 00007f2499620520
12-15 21:09:25.392 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     rsi 0000000000000001  rdi 00007f249cf462c0
12-15 21:09:25.392 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     r8  0000000000000055  r9  00007f249892b300  r10 00007f249892b630  r11 00007f249892b641
12-15 21:09:25.393 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     r12 00007f249892b630  r13 00007f2485ff1800  r14 0000000000000001  r15 00000000132baf60
12-15 21:09:25.393 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     cs  0000000000000033  ss  000000000000002b
12-15 21:09:25.393 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     rip 00007f249cf2501a  rbp 00007f2499620520  rsp 00007f249892b630  eflags 0000000000010202
12-15 21:09:25.393 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
12-15 21:09:25.393 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     #00 pc 000000000004501a  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::releaseObjects()+58)
12-15 21:09:25.393 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000004510c  /system/lib64/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::freeDataNoInit()+44)
12-15 21:09:25.393 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00000000000f1c40  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
12-15 21:09:25.393 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000000000021de9  /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/system@framework@boot.oat
12-15 21:09:26.256 1128-1128/? I/DEBUG: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
12-15 21:09:26.470 1556-4425/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 in.myapp.dev/com.myapp.dev.ui.activities.MainLandingActivity
12-15 21:09:26.479 1556-1577/system_process D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-15 21:09:26.523 1556-1570/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{1762341d u0 in.myapp.dev/com.myapp.dev.ui.activities.SplashActivity}
12-15 21:09:26.547 1556-1571/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{63c6f2e u0 in.myapp.dev/com.myapp.dev.ui.activities.MainLandingActivity}
12-15 21:09:26.551 1556-2114/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{ba26c8d u0 in.myapp.dev}
12-15 21:09:26.552 1556-1838/system_process I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{97dfeaf u0 in.myapp.dev/com.myapp.dev.ui.activities.OrganisationActivity}
12-15 21:09:26.555 1135-1135/? I/Zygote: Process 2865 exited due to signal (11)
```

Here is the link to tombstone file.
[Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19Vjoey_yKmN7s_VOyxbLA60UXloFz_IT/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue out of the blue. The app was working jsut fine then suddenly this occurs one day then it won't stop happening at random times. Have you fixed yours already @pradex?

Comment: @JojoNarté added the answer, pl check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So for me, the problem was parsing Google's Location object with Gson. I created my own SimpleLocation object and it solved the problem. Google's Location object was throwing random Signal 11 error and crashing randomly.

Here is a link to similar problem with better explanation https://github.com/e-mission/e-mission-data-collection/issues/49

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution.  I'd like to investigate if this has been fixed upstream, could you share which libraries and versions you were using?

Comment: @CodeShane I was using android.location.Location; with 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'