# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) crash only on some devices

Tags: android, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I have been getting this crash on Xiaomi devices mainly while on most other devices the crash does not occur. The crash seems random and happens anytime while using the app. I cant seem to find any solution and Do no know how to track down the crash. Any help would be useful. Below are the crash logs.

```
2019-03-05 15:11:50.992 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'xiaomi/cereus/cereus:8.1.0/O11019/V10.0.6.0.OCGMIFH:user/release-keys'
2019-03-05 15:11:50.992 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2019-03-05 15:11:50.992 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2019-03-05 15:11:50.992 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG: pid: 15781, tid: 15794, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.avadna.luneblaze <<<
2019-03-05 15:11:50.993 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x2
2019-03-05 15:11:50.993 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference
2019-03-05 15:11:50.993 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     r0 aba25568  r1 00000006  r2 00000006  r3 00000002
2019-03-05 15:11:50.993 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     r4 aba25568  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 91b56c48
2019-03-05 15:11:50.993 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     r8 00000000  r9 a329a200  sl 00000000  fp 91b569ec
2019-03-05 15:11:50.993 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     ip 00000002  sp 91b56950  lr ad8c2b19  pc 00000002  cpsr 20070010
2019-03-05 15:11:51.124 16638-16659/? I/zygote: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
2019-03-05 15:11:51.277 565-565/? I/Proximity: distance = 1
2019-03-05 15:11:51.364 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-03-05 15:11:51.364 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000002  <unknown>
2019-03-05 15:11:51.364 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00046b17  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::freeDataNoInit()+34)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.364 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00046aed  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::Parcel::~Parcel()+4)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000bb52d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::android_os_Parcel_destroy(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long long)+6)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 005f23bf  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x5f1000) (android.os.Binder.restoreCallingIdentity [DEDUPED]+102)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 00406775  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0040b9eb  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+226)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 000b0317  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+174)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00201973  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+226)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 001fcf01  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+592)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 003f19a5  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+184)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 003f8d94  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 001e3955  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+344)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 001e8019  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+148)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 001fcee9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 003f1837  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+250)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 003f8d14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 001e3955  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+344)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 001e8019  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+148)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 001fcee9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 003f098b  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+482)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 003f8c14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.365 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 001e3955  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+344)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 001e8019  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+148)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 001fcee9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 003f1837  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+250)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 003f8d14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14484)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 001e3955  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+344)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 001e8019  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+148)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #29 pc 001fcee9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #30 pc 003f098b  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+482)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #31 pc 003f8c14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14228)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #32 pc 001e3955  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+344)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #33 pc 001e8019  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+148)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #34 pc 001fcee9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+568)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #35 pc 003f1577  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1078)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #36 pc 003f8e14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14740)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #37 pc 001e3955  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool)+344)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #38 pc 001e7f61  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::DexFile::CodeItem const*, art::ShadowFrame*)+92)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #39 pc 003e6275  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+924)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #40 pc 0040acf1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #41 pc 00406775  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.366 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #42 pc 0040b8e5  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+228)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.367 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #43 pc 000b02f3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+138)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.367 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #44 pc 003571f1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+52)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.367 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #45 pc 00357fe7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+322)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.367 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #46 pc 00377ac9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+836)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.367 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #47 pc 00047507  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+22)
2019-03-05 15:11:51.367 16683-16683/? A/DEBUG:     #48 pc 0001af75  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+32)
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution and seems to be working for me as of now. The issue was trying to parse google location object with Gson. Seems like you should not try parsing native classes for some reason.

[Same issue as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923830/10101972)

Comment: Happens to me though it is not having any location API

Comment: Also, I got the problem when parsing Location object with Gson.